# How to unblock sites in squid proxy server

Tags: fedora, squid, yum

I have installed Squid as proxy server,By default it block the yum install and mails(gmail,yahoomail,etc).How to unblock this functions.i'm using fedora13 as OS

Comment: The 'normal' squid install doesn't block stuff like that by default, so either you've installed more than just squid or something is odd about the way it is configured

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to make sure who is blocking you. Squid by default does not block specific sites/URLs.

If you are sure you are getting blocked because of squid, you can look for the `acl`, `http allow` and `http deny` configuration options. There are many options that can check for IPs, URLs, domains, etc. Of course, you need to have super user access to modify the configuration if needed.